# Couldnt find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'coreclr'(extension might have failed to activate)

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug this simple web app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace HttpCookies
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var cookie = context.Request.Cookies["MyCoolLittleCookie"];

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie))
                {
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime expires = now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append
                    (
                        "MyCoolLittleCookie",
                        "Cookie created at: " + now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"),
                        new CookieOptions
                        {
                            Path = "/",
                            HttpOnly = false,
                            Secure = false,
                            Expires = expires
                        }
                    );
                }

                string response =
                    "<h1>HTTP Cookies</h1>" +
                    $"<p>This is the cookie value received from browser: \"<strong>{cookie}</strong>\".</p>" +
                    "<p>Refresh page to see current cookie value...</p>" +
                    "<p>Cookie expires after 15 seconds.</p>";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/HttpCookies.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

and when i try to debug this error shows up

"Couldnt find a debug adapter descriptor  for debug type 'coreclr'(extension might have failed to activate)"

What should i do to stop this error? it was working fine but suddenly this error started popping up,
please help

Comment: No images of code. Please post code as text

Comment: @AluanHaddad i posted the code

Comment: where did you find to set the `"type": "coreclr"`, do you have installed the correct extension

Comment: @rioV8 when i opened the launch.json file it was there. and yes i installed the C# extension(Microsoft)

Comment: I fixed it by completely uninstalling the Omnisharp extension, then re-installing it. Originally caused by some dot net upgrade issue reversion.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by uninstalling all c# extensions and .Net extensions.Then installed C# by microsoft and C# Extension by jchannon and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling a C# extension that was installed from a VSIX.

Still have the C# extension from Microsoft installed.

Afterwards, the web API could be run and debugged.